# Copy or clone the entire row of records in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a my records or rows displaying in a while loop in PHP. I got a Add New href link before all the records. When the users press the Add New link the clone of the record is copied below. The admin will change that record as per his wish. This is the actual scenario.

I have pasted my script below. Its almost done. But when i click Add New (+) link, its cloning the text box but not the value of the row. So how will i pass the value of the text box to the javascript and jquery?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Clone</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

<style type='text/css'>
a{text-decoration:none;}
</style>


 <script type='text/javascript'>
 $(window).load(function(){
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var i = 0;

$('.addNew').on('click', function() {
    $('<tr class="clone"><td><input type="text" id="p_new'+i+'" name="data[]" value="" ><a href="#" class="remNew">-</a><td> </tr>').appendTo($(this).parent('td'));
    i++;

    return false;
});

$('.remNew').live('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).parentsUntil('tr.clone').attr('id');
    if( id != '0' ) {
      $(this).parentsUntil('tr.clone').remove();
      i--;
    }
    return false;
});
});
 });//]]>  

 </script>


 </head>
 <body>
   <table border="1">
        <tr>

        <td id="addinput">
            <input type="text" id="p_new" name="data[]" value="Show in Child element 1" ><a href="#" class="addNew">Add New</a>
        </td>
        </tr>
           <tr>           
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="p_new_1" name="data[]" value="Show in Child element 2" ><a href="#" class="addNew">Add New</a>
        </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</body>
</html>



 Iam pasting the PHP part below:

 <?php
//mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
//mysql_select_db("test") or die("Unable to select database");
 include('config.php');

 $tender_id=$_GET['tender_id'];

echo "<form name='cart' method='post' class='single' action='generate_quot_cust_edititems_save.php?tender_id=$tender_id' >\n";

echo "<input type='hidden' name='sum_input' id='sum_input' value=''>";

$sql = "select id,slno,item_name,qty,item_units,unitprice,currency,total,total_inr,add_percentage,add_percentage_v,add_value,addon_value,price_unit,grand_total,tech_amend_req from quotation_items where tender_id='$tender_id'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

$i = 0;

echo '<table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">';
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td></td>";
echo '<td>SlNo</td>';
echo '<td>Description</td>';
echo '<td>Qty</td>';
echo '<td>Units</td>';
echo '<td>Unit Price</td>';
echo '<td>Currency</td>';
echo '<td>Total</td>';
echo '<td>Total INR</td>';
echo '<td>Add Percentage(%)</td>';
echo '<td>Add On Value</td>';
echo '<td>Total Value</td>';
echo '<td>Price/Unit</td>';
echo '</tr>';

 //if($list5['tech_amend_req'] === '1') echo checked='checked'
while ($list5 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 //$tech_amend_req=$list5['tech_amend_req'];
 if ($list5['tech_amend_req'] == '0') $checked = '';
 if ($list5['tech_amend_req'] == '') $checked = '';
 if ($list5['tech_amend_req'] == '1') $checked = 'checked=checked';

 //echo $checked;
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='tech_amend_req[$i]'    id='tech_amend_req[$i]' value='1' $checked/></td>";
    echo "<td><input size='2' type='text' name='id[$i]' value='{$list5['id']}' readonly/></td>";
    echo "<td id='addinput'><input type='text' id='item_name$i' name='item_name[$i]' placeholder='{$list5['item_name']}' value='{$list5['item_name']}' /><a href='#' class='addNew'>+</a></td>";
    echo "<td><input size='2' type='text' name='qty[]' id='qty[]' value='{$list5['qty']}' readonly/></td>";
    echo "<td><input size='2' type='text' name='item_units[$i]' value='{$list5['item_units']}' readonly/></td>";
    echo "<td><input size='5' type='text' size='40' name='unitprice[$i]' value='{$list5['unitprice']}' readonly/></td>";
    echo "<td><input size='3' type='text' size='40' name='currency[$i]' value='{$list5['currency']}' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input size='6' type='text' size='40' name='total_old' value='{$list5['total']}' readonly/></td>";
    echo "<td><input size='6' type='text' size='40' id='total_inr[]' name='total_inr[]' value='{$list5['total_inr']}'/></td>";
    echo "<td><input class='' size='6' type='text' size='40' id='add_percentage[]' name='add_percentage[]' value='{$list5['add_percentage']}' onchange='calcTotals()'></td>";

    echo "<td><input class='' size='6' type='text' size='40' id='addon_value[]' name='addon_value[]' value='{$list5['addon_value']}' onchange='calcTotals()'></td>";

    echo "<td><input class='txt' size='6' type='text' size='40' id='add_value[]' name='add_value[]' value='{$list5['add_value']}' readonly></td>";
    echo "<td><input class='txt' size='6' type='text' size='40' id='price_unit[]' name='price_unit[]' value='{$list5['price_unit']}' readonly></td>";

    ++$i;
}

 $sql = "select grand_total from quotation_items where tender_id='$tender_id' LIMIT 1";

 $result_gt = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
 $list_gt = mysql_fetch_array($result_gt);

 echo "<tr><td  colspan=10></td><td><b>Grand Total:</b></td><td height=35><b><input style='font-weight: bold' name='gTotal' id='grand_total' value='{$list_gt['grand_total']}' readonly /></b></td></tr>";
echo '<tr></table>';
```

?>

Comment: It is not cloning. It is appending a raw HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [clone table row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223557/clone-table-row)

Comment: What do you mean by > the clone of the record is copied below.

Comment: For Example: i have some records displaying. and there will a Add New (+) after each row. When i click the add new link, that particular <tr> ---</tr> clone has to be copied below the row, i mean with the value or data.

1. John, john@john.com  - Add New(+)
2. Ahmad, ahmad@ahmad.com - Add New(+)
3. sujith, sujith@sujith.com - Add New(+)

Comment: In short, the value of the text box has to be copied or cloned below the <tr>. As of now it is not copying the value of the text box. its copying a blank text box. Kindly help..

Comment: So you mean when I press _Add new_ the value 'Show in Child element 1' at first click should appear in new input. Then if I change the value of the new input, that should appear in the new input that is added after clicking _Add new_ and so on. Is that so?

Comment: Yes Exactly, what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'd recommend you use two separate tables for your purpose (*and not append rows to a `td` element*).

Hence, your html would look like this:

```
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td class="addinput">
                <input type="text" id="p_new" name="data[]" value="Show in Child element 1" ><a href="#" class="addNew">Add New</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>           
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="p_new_1" name="data[]" value="Show in Child element 2" ><a href="#" class="addNew">Add New</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Then, in your Javascript, you can make use of jQuery's `clone()` method, whick literary ***clones*** a matched element. Here I've used it to clone a whole table row, and then **appended** it to the relative table.

```
$('.addNew').on('click', function() {
    var removeLink = '<a href="#" class="remNew">-</a>';
    var row = $(this).closest('table').find('tr:last-child').clone();

    row.find('a').attr('class', 'remNew');
    row.find('a').html('-');

    $(this).closest('table').append(row);

     //register for the 'removeLink' on click, so that it deletes the row
    row.find('a').click(function(){
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }); 
});
```

**Have a look at [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/qckb4bau/) on jsfiddle.net.**

Comment: Absolutely Great. It is working fantastic. Thanx a lot bro.

Answer (score 3):

I have edited your code and this is working perfect. Try this:

```
              <!DOCTYPE html>
              <html>
               <head>
              <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                <title>Clone</title>
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                  <script type="text/javascript">

                      function addRow() {

                          var myRow = '<tr><td> <input type="text" id="p_new" name="data[]" value="some value" ></td></tr>';

                          $("#MyTable tr:last").after(myRow);

                      }

                  </script>


               </script>


               </head>
               <body>
                <div onclick="addRow()" style="color: Blue; text-decoration: underline;">

                      Add row to table

                  </div>
                 <table border="1"  id="MyTable">
                      <tr>

                      <td id="addinput">
                          <input type="text" id="p_new" name="data[]" value="some value" >
                      </td>
                      </tr>

                  </table>

              </body>
              </html>
```

Let me know if your problem is solved or not.
Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But it is not copying or cloning the value of the text box. It is showing a blank textbox.

Comment: Write something in the text box. And if it works, plz upvote and tick my answer :)

Comment: I am displaying the results in an array in php from a while loop. 

while ($list5 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<td id='addinput'><input type='text' id='item_name$i' name='item_name[$i]' placeholder='{$list5['item_name']}' value='{$list5['item_name']}' /><a href='#' class='addNew'>+</a></td>";

i++;
}

This value has to be cloned actually. Not the hard coded value.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have added the php part to the question as well now.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this,
HTML:

```
<div id="add" style="color: Blue; text-decoration: underline;">
  Add row to table
</div>
<table border="1"  id="MyTable">
  <tr>
    <td id="addinput">
      <input type="text" id="p_new" name="data[]" value="" >
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var i = 0;
var value;

$("#add").on('click', function() {
  if ($("#MyTable").find('tr').length > 1) {
    value = $("#p_new" + (i-1)).val();
  } else {
    value = $("#p_new").val();
  }
  var myRow = '<tr><td> <input type="text" id="p_new' + i + '" name="data[]" value="' + value + '" ></td></tr>';
  i++;
  $("#MyTable").append(myRow);
});
```

Working [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJoMYq?editors=101)